# Powershell (linux) while loop to check if a file exists OR a word is typed

Tags: powershell, while-loop, conditional-statements

I'm having an issue with a portion of a function I'm trying to write (it is stuck in the loop, Read-Host portion indefinitely).

```
while (!(Test-Path -Path /userpub/$pub_file/ -PathType Leaf) -or ($pub_file = "Exit"))
       {
        [string]$pub_file = Read-Host  "Enter in the correct filename or type Exit to quit: "
       }
```

Input string for **$pub_file** = **"ABCD"**
The file in **/userpub/** is named **pubtest.txt**

If I type in **pubtest.txt** or **Exit** or even **ABCD**, it still just keeps prompting for input.

ANSWER with thanks to MathiasR.Jessen in the comments:

```
while (!(Test-Path -Path /userpub/$pub_file -PathType Leaf) -and ($pub_file -ne 'Exit'))
           {
            [string]$pub_file = Read-Host  "Enter in the correct filename or type Exit to quit: "
           }
```

Comment: You probably wanna remove the trailing `/` in the file path and replace `($pub_file = "Exit")` with `$pub_file -eq 'Exit'` - the `=` is only for _assignments_, not comparisons :)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen we're getting closer! With your changes it exits on the actual filename; however entering Exit still makes it loop. It is almost as if the **-or** is being skipped.

Comment: Change the `-or` to `-and`, and change `-eq` to `-ne`, that should do the trick :)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen That worked! Now to figure out how to give you the credit. :)

Comment: I posted a proper answer below, click the checkmark on the left of it to mark it "accepted" :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the following changes:

- Remove the trailing `/` from the file path
- Change the `-or` to an `-and`

  - Remember, you only want to keep prompting when the file name doesn't exists
    *and* the user didn't input `Exit`
- Change the `=` to `-ne`:

```
while (!(Test-Path -Path /userpub/$pub_file -PathType Leaf) -and $pub_file -ne "Exit")
{
    [string]$pub_file = Read-Host  "Enter in the correct filename or type Exit to quit: "
}
```

One final tweak you might want to make: Assuming that you never want to test for a file named `exit`, make sure you test for that condition *first*, but flip the loop around so you prompt the user before checking the condition:

```
do {
    [string]$pub_file = Read-Host  "Enter in the correct filename or type Exit to quit: "
} while ($pub_file -ne "Exit" -and -not(Test-Path -Path /userpub/$pub_file -PathType Leaf))
```